Energy functional - must $\gamma$ be parameterized by arc length?
I was reading up on geodesics and came across the following statement: We can either solve the length functional
$$ L[\gamma]=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|\gamma'(t)\| \,\, dt \,, $$
or the energy functional given by
$$ E[\gamma]=\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|\gamma'(t)\|^2 \,\, dt \,. $$
I am not sure but I suspect the two approaches are only equivalent when the energy functional is evaluated with $\gamma(t)$ being proportional to arc length, while the length functional can work with an arbitrary parameterization of $\gamma(t)$. Is my assumption correct?

It's always best to make everything precise here. When you say "the two approaches are only equivalent", what exactly do you mean? You'll find that making the effort to express your vague thoughts precisely often allows you to answer your own question.

I'll explain why we solve for critical points of $E$ when we are looking for minimizers of $L$. Say $\gamma$ is your length minimizing curve. Say you have a family of curves $\gamma(s, \cdot) : [a, b] \to M$, $s \in (-h, h)$ with $\gamma(s, a) = p$, $\gamma(s, b) = q$ with $\gamma(0, \cdot) = \gamma$. Then $\frac{d}{ds}L(\gamma(s, \cdot))|_{s = 0} = 0$. Since length is invariant under reparameterization, you can reparameterize all the curves $\gamma(s, \cdot)$, $s \in (-h, h)$ so that $\gamma(0, \cdot)$ is parameterized to have constant speed $c_0$. Then you can show that $\frac{d}{ds}L(\gamma(s, \cdot))|_{s = 0} = \frac{1}{c_0}\frac{d}{ds}E(\gamma(s, \cdot))|_{s = 0}$. This proves that if $\gamma$ is a critical point of $L$, then the constant speed reparameterization of $\gamma$ is a critical point of $E$.
See any differential geometry book ,e.g. chapter 6 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf for more detail.

"This proves that if $\gamma$ is a critical point of $L$, then the constant speed reparameterization of $\gamma$ is a critical point of $E$" - I think I get the gist of it, but how many curves in real life admit being parameterized proportional to arc-length, so that we can go the easier route with the energy functional?

@user358572 If $\gamma : [a, b] \to M$ is a $C^1$ curve and $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [a, b]$, then $\gamma$ can be parameterized by arc-length. So any such regular curve can be parameterized by arclength. Actually from my argument you can conclude that a regular curve $\gamma$ is a critical point of $L$ if and only if a constant speed parameterization $\gamma_{cs}$ is a crtitical point of $E$. So all regular critical points of $L$ can be found as reparameterizations of constant speed critical points of $E$ (it turns out all critical points of $E$ have constant speed).

My comment above was actually about obtaining the arc-length parameterization as an explicit formula, not merely knowing that it exists because $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$. I am looking at this from an application-side of things, not pure math (e.g. take the unit paraboloid of revolution and find geodesics using (1) the length functional, and (2) the energy functional).

In mathematics, the term "geodesic" refers to critical points of $E$, that is, $\gamma$ is called a geodesic if and only if $\gamma$ is a critical point of $E$. In applications, given $\gamma(a) = p$ and $\gamma'(p) = v$, the critical point equation for $\gamma$ is an ODE for $\gamma$, which can be solved by standard ODE solving techniques.
